# How to ask user if he wants to start program all over again if he typed a char/string instead of a number?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, double

I'm new here and new to Java, started like 1-2 weeks ago and I wanted to make an app that is applying pythagora's theory. All done, but now I'm stuck in a place where I want the user to be asked if he wants to try again, start again, if he enters a character or string instead of a number.

What am I doing wrong? This is my code, I've added comments too so it would be easier in case you don't understand what I was trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

```
package pitagoracalculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PitagoraCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double nr1;
            double nr2;
            double ipot;
            boolean raspuns;
            String raspuns1;

            do{
                try{
                    //user is asked for first number
                    System.out.print("Introduceti primul numar: ");
                    nr1 = input.nextDouble();

                    //user is asked for second number
                    System.out.print("Introduceti al 2-lea numar: ");
                    nr2 = input.nextDouble();

                    //result of calculation
                    ipot = (nr1*nr1)+(nr2*nr2);
                    System.out.println("Rezultatul este: "+ipot+"^2");

                //in case user inserts a string/char instead of a double => error
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.err.println("Nu ati introdus un numar.");
                    break;
                }

                //user is asked if he wants to do another calculation
                System.out.println("Doriti sa faceti un alt calcul? (da/nu)");
                raspuns1 = input.next();

                //if his answer is yes, raspuns = true, else raspuns = false
                if(raspuns1.equalsIgnoreCase("da"))
                    raspuns = true;
                else{
                    System.out.println("La revedere!");
                    raspuns = false;
                }

            //checks if the answer was true or false
            }while(raspuns == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to bounce the user back to the beginning in your `catch` block,  or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes. Let's say he's running the program and he enters 'g' instead of a number, as it is right now it will execute: System.err.println and will end the program. I want to jump back at the top and ask him again for a number or maybe ask him if he wants try again and if his answer is yes to ask him for a number. I'm curious how can I achieve the two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
//in case user inserts a string/char instead of a double => error
} catch (Exception e){
   System.err.println("Nu ati introdus un numar.");
   break;
}
```

with

```
//in case user inserts a string/char instead of a double => error
} catch (Exception e){
   System.err.println("Nu ati introdus un numar.");
   //clear pending input.
   if (input.hasNext()) {
        input.next();
   }
   continue;
}
```

"break" exits the loop, "continue" will continue with the next cycle of the loop.

You also have to initialize the raspuns variable with true

```
boolean raspuns = true;
```

Comment: It tells me: "variable raspuns might not have been initialized." and can't be built. I have 2 variables, "raspuns1" holds the answer as string (yes/no) and than that answer is converted to a boolean "raspuns" as true or false. The error is at: while (raspuns == true); last line of code.

Comment: Also you do not have to "convert" the answer to a boolean variable. You can do the check inside the while condition.
`while ("da".equalsIgnoreCase(raspuns1));`

Answer (score 0):

You can call method in exceptional case.For this you should make a method in same class and put your all stuff in that method use if-else loop..

Comment: Initially that's what I did. Created a method, but didn't get to make it work. My knowledge in programming is quite limited for now.